# String declarations and assignments: 3 methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, nsstring

For non-retained string declarations, are these three lines the same?

```
NSString *list2 = self.map;

NSString *list2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.map];

NSString *list2 = [NSString stringWithString:self.map];
```

They all create an autoreleased string object, right? Is there a preferred method among these, or are there any differences in the memory usage or behavior of "list2" depending on these methods?

For some reason, I find the manipulation of strings in objective-C the most confusing transition from other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They all create an autoreleased string object, right?

No, the first one merely assigns the pointer returned by `string.map` to `list2`.  The second and third ones theoretically create new `NSStrings` that you don't own and assign them to `list2`.  However, if `string.map` returns an immutable string, the third one will *probably* give you the same pointer (possibly retained and autoreleased).

In all cases you do not own the (new) string.  That's actually all you need to know.  They may be autoreleased, but it is not relevant to you using them.

Comment: @Mike Weller: No the statement is not false.  `self.map` is a property which in reality means that `[self map]` is being called and it returns a pointer that may or may not have been autoreleased depending on how the accessor implemented.  In particular, if `nonatomic` is specified and the property was synthesized, it will definitely not have been autoreleased.

Comment: You are correct that it may or may not be autoreleased, but most default getter implementations will do a [[ivar retain] autorelease] to prevent later setter calls from invalidating any previously returned values. I'm pretty sure this is how a synthesized (retain) property is implemented.

Comment: So, my first example code line would technically create a new retained object if self.map is retained, thus I have essentially added to my memory use and must [list2 release] later, right? edit: actually, i'm guessing i'm wrong since i'm not "copying". it's just a duplicate pointer to the same single object, right?

Comment: @andrewjs: No.  None of those three lines give you ownership of the object.  If `map` is a `copy` property, you may get a copy of the object but you do not own it.  If you want to keep it around, you must explicitly retain it.  This is the point, you can't guarantee that it is a copy, the same object, autoreleased or whatever.  All you know and all you need to know is that you do not own it.

Comment: @Mike Weller: the point is that in the first case, if an autorelease is done, it is **before** `self.map` returns.  So my statement "the first one merely assigns the pointer returned by `string.map`" is 100% correct.

Comment: regarding ownership, as i would not own any of these (which I knew that much already), at what point can I assume that I should not access them? they only exist until the end of the method runs that contains/declares them?

Comment: @andrewjs: None of the above are safe to access after the current autorelease pool has been drained/released. Also the first one could disappear (depending on the implementation) any time self is modified.

Answer (score 2):

The simple fact, **You don't own the object in the above three cases**, 
So you could use either,
This is more related to choice of developer then performance.

Go through the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)